# Waiting for async to be completed

Tags: dart, flutter

I currently have something like this

```
   Future<bool>  checkAvailability(String email) async {
        var client = new http.Client();
        var response = await client.get(host);
        bool result;
        if (response.statusCode == 404) {
             result= true;
        }
        else if (response.statusCode == 200) {
              result= false;
        }
        client.close();
        return result;
    }
```

I am calling the above method from a regular non-aysnc function
in this way

```
void test() {
    checkAvailability(email).then((result){....}
       );
}
```

The problem with the above code is that its async. From what I understand is that Once `checkAvailability` is called its launched in a different thread ? and the ui (main) thread continues? Am I correct?

What I would like to do is to have `test` function wait for the result of `checkAvailability`. I know I can use await but then the method `test` will need to be marked as `async` and when this method is called it will be launched in a different thread. What I want is for the call to `checkAvailability` be synchronous and I don't mind waiting for a response.

Comment: You can't really transform an async call into a sync one.

Comment: What's the problem with using `await` with `test`?

Answer (score 3):

> Once checkAvailability is called its launched in a different thread ?

Async execution is not related to threads, async works with an event queue https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop

> `test` will need to be marked as `async` and when this method is called it will be launched in a different thread.

As mentioned before, it won't be another thread. Using `async` on a `test` method usually works fine. Why do you try to avoid it?

> What I want is for the call to checkAvailability be synchronous and I dont mind waiting for a response.

If you don't care about the result, just don't await it, although this would also cause the calling code to continue before `checkAvailability` was completed.

> What I want is for the call to checkAvailability be synchronous and I dont mind waiting for a response.

There is no way to go back from async execution to sync execution. Once an async call is made, it's completion and the result will always be a `Future` and needs to be awaited or handled by `.then(...)`.

If you don't care when `checkAvailability` completes and don't need a result from async calls it makes, then you don't need to `await` or use `then(...)`. Just call the method and that's it.